# Where and how did magical genes in Harry Potter originate?

Tags: harry-potter

Did magical genes result from a slight change in the Human DNA? If so, who was(were) the first wizards? If they were pureblood magical wizards, how are the wizards today still pureblood, assuming that they may have bred with muggles?

Or was magic a sentient form that to earth from the heavens (other planets, species from wherever in the universe) and fuse with themselves with humans to create magical genes?

Did the magical gene distribute itself evenly among earth's population?

Comment: Worth noting is that "pureblood" is to a certain extent a term tied to a racial ideology. That is, there are likely no real purebloods: merely wizards whose Muggle ancestry is too far back to be recorded.

Comment: It's great that you're asking so many questions, but you seem to be ignoring the "suggested duplicates" that come up during posting. The duplicate to this one was at #3 on that list.